# Return value from an HTML class/scope?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a webpage that I'm trying to return a value from, however I can't find the right way to grab it with Selenium.

Here's the relevant HTML part:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <th scope="row"><a style="cursor: pointer"
            onClick="document.formShip.P_IMO.value='9526942';document.formShip.submit();">
                9526942</a>
        </th>
```

I'm trying to get `9526942`.

I've tried:

```
imo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'document.formShip.P_IMO.value')]")
```

and looked around [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), but don't know what element this is.  I tried looking for the class `hidden-sm hidden-xs`, to no avail:

```
imo = driver.find_element_by_class_name('hidden-sm hidden-xs')
```

Comment: You wouldn't care to divulge what page it is, would you? It appears to be about a container ship.

Comment: @BillBell - Yep - it's from www.equasis.org, AFAIK you need a login (found that site via [here](https://www.marineinsight.com/tech/what-is-equasis-shipping-database/). I am just looking for a quick way to get the IMO numbers of various ships. (I've looked around for APIs and there are some, I just figured this way would be quickest since I use that site anyways.)

Comment: I should have known!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get the text you need to use .text. The .text method can be used with a webelement which some text in that.

in your first example which you tried, you are passing a different parameter with text(). usually when you use text(), you need to pass the value which is there between closing and open tags (the text which you see on the screen)

you simply try this.

```
  imo = driver.find_element_by_xpath(.//tr[@class='hidden-sm hidden-xs']).text
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm getting an `Invalid Syntax` error with the `@` highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - still same error with `.` highlighted.  Note I edited my OP to include that it's in a table.  I'm getting somewhere with `imo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped']").text` but it's returning a bunch of info. Still trying to just get that one specific number.  Edit: Ooh! Getting there! I think I can use this and then just parse out the additional info it has: `imo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='hidden-sm hidden-xs']").text`

Comment: it is a good practice to use .text with the end tag, in your example td. Just try to write the dynamic xpath for your td tag and use .text with that.
imo = driver.find_element_by_xpath(.//tr[@class='hidden-sm hidden-xs']/td).text
Note: make sure the variable imo should be of type string.